# Ansible: how can I use "sudo su -c <COMMAND> <USER>" to execute a command as another user?

Tags: automation, ansible

I am helping a colleague automate some manual tasks on a server farm. He has to perform administrative tasks on applications but has limited rights within the OS itself (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7).

A big problem is that he can't use sudo in order to execute commands as another user. He is required by the actual admin to execute commands as another user by using

```sh
    sudo su -c "<COMMAND>" <USERNAME>
```

There doesn't seem to be a builtin become plugin that would support this. No problem for simple remote command invocations using the shell module, where I can code the "sudo su -c" into the command that will be invoked remotely. But for all the other Ansible modules I would like to do something like

```yaml
    become: yes
    become_user: ...
    become_method: sudo_and_su
```

What is the best way to do that? Do I have to write a custom become plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `become` and `become_method` in your playbook as below:

```yaml
become: yes
become_method: su
```

and you need to change the parameter `become_exe`.

You could change it before running playbook export below env variable on host server:

```yaml
ANSIBLE_BECOME_EXE=’sudo su -‘
```

or change it in `ansible.cfg` file

```yaml
[privilege_escalation]
become_exe = ’sudo su -‘
```